# Characters Å Ä Ö is not getting displayed in my DDL, how can I tell restclient to utilize a specific charset?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

Before I start here is the problem. It should be like this:

Björn Nilsson, instead its displaying strange special characters, all values that have  characters Å, Ä and Ö  becomes like this.

[image]

I fill my DDL with values from API in XML format that has all the values, and we are also using Linq2Rest for that.

This how the process looks like

```
 private readonly RestContext<ADConsultants> restContext;

public ConsultantContext(Uri uri, Format format)
{
    restContext = new RestContext<ADConsultants>(GetRestClient(uri, format), GetSerializerFactory(format));
}
public enum Format
{
    Pox,
    Json
}

private static readonly IEnumerable<Type> knownTypes = new[] {typeof (ADConsultants)};

public static IRestClient GetRestClient(Uri uri, Format format)
{
    switch (format)
    {
        case Format.Pox:
            return new XmlRestClient(uri);
        case Format.Json:
            return new JsonRestClient(uri);
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
private static ISerializerFactory GetSerializerFactory(Format format)
{
    switch (format)
    {
        case Format.Pox:
            return new XmlSerializerFactory(knownTypes);
        case Format.Json:
            return new JsonNetSerializerFactory();
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
public IQueryable<ADConsultants> Consultant
{
    get { return restContext.Query; }
}
```

}

This is my JsonNetSerializerFactory class:

```
public class JsonNetSerializerFactory :ISerializerFactory 
{
    public ISerializer<T> Create<T>()
    {
        return new JsonNetSerializer<T>();
    }
    public class JsonNetSerializer<T> : ISerializer<T>
    {
        public T Deserialize(string input)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(input);
        }

        public IList<T> DeserializeList(string input)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<T>>(input);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is inside my controller:

```
var consultants = new ConsultantContext(
        new Uri("http://adress:port/api/consultants"),
                ConsultantContext.Format.Json)
                    .Consultant
                    .Where(x => x.Office == "Örebro")  
                    .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName)  
                    .ToList() 
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        name = x.DisplayName
                    });
```

I did a test by doing this:

```
name = "åäö"
```

and it worked fine, ddl values was "åäö"

Any help is appreciated on how to fix so characters Å Ä Ö works fine as values in my DDL.

HTTP header is utf-8, my html content have it aswell. It must be the XML that need to be set to a specific charset, How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the content encoding of your output? It looks like your data layer outputs UTF-8, but the presentation layer declares it as some other encoding.

Comment: I dont understand your question but I am using <meta charset="utf-8"> on the whole content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the theory you got an charset encoding/decoding problem.

the Cause: the content you try to read has been encoded using a charset like iso-8859-1 or iso-8859-15. and you'll try to read (decode) it directly to an "UTF-8" character Model. Of course it won't work because UTF-8 because UTF-8 won't in a  miracle recognize your special chars (Ä,Ü, Ö, and so on..). UTF-8 is no guesser for character coding.

**Solution**:

1- (Re)encode your content( e.g "Björn Nilsson") with its corresponding charset (iso-8859-1/iso-8859-15) into Byte collection.

2- Decode your content with into  "UTF-8" based charset.

here an Helper Class as example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

    namespace csharp.util.charset
    {
        public class SysUtil
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Convert a string from one charset to another charset
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="strText">source string</param>
            /// <param name="strSrcEncoding">original encoding name</param>
            /// <param name="strDestEncoding">dest encoding name</param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public static String StringEncodingConvert(String strText, String strSrcEncoding, String strDestEncoding)
            {
                System.Text.Encoding srcEnc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(strSrcEncoding);
                System.Text.Encoding destEnc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(strDestEncoding);
                byte[] bData=srcEnc.GetBytes(strText);
                byte[] bResult = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(srcEnc, destEnc, bData);
                return destEnc.GetString(bResult);
            }

        }
    }
```

**Usage:**

in your (JSON-, XML, other) serializer/deserializer  classes just convert your content like that

```
String content = "Björn Nilsson";
SysUtil.StringEncodingConvert(content, "ISO-8859-1","UTF-8");
```

you could try to make your calls in your deserializer (if they really do what they mean):

```
public class JsonNetSerializerFactory :ISerializerFactory 
{
    public ISerializer<T> Create<T>()
    {
        return new JsonNetSerializer<T>();
    }
    public class JsonNetSerializer<T> : ISerializer<T>
    {
        public T Deserialize(string input, String fromCharset, String toCharset)

        {
           String changedString = SysUtil.StringEncodingConvert(input, fromCharset,toCharset);

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(changedString  );
        }

        public IList<T> DeserializeList(string input, String fromCharset, String toCharset)
        {
         String changedString =  SysUtil.StringEncodingConvert(input, fromCharset,toCharset);

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<T>>(changedString);
        }
    }
}
```

that's for your

```
JsonNetSerializerFactory
```

please try to do same for other factories like

```
XmlSerializerFactory
```

and don't forget your setting in your HTML-page

```
<meta charset="utf-8"> <!--HTML 5 -->

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> <!-- if HTML version < 5-->
```

Comment: Could you give me an example where in my code I should type  SysUtil.StringEncodingConvert(xmlContent, "ISO-8859-1","UTF-8");

Comment: @RammtinAvar I edited my answer and made a proposal on where to place it in your code. Note that it might not work, because I do not know how you fully coded your stuff. let me know if it fails, so that you can continue this in a chat. if it work don't forget to vote my answer up.

Answer (score 1):

There is most likely a mismatch between the character set of the text and what the browser interprets as the character set.

Do you have a `<meta>` tag for content or charset?

Given the character set you send is UTF-8, and you are using HTML5, this would be the appropriate tag

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Or in earlier versions of HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

For `iso-8859-1` or any other charset, just replace the `charset` attribute.

Comment: Do you know for sure that the server sends the data as utf-8? Have you tried to tell your browser to try another charset?

Comment: Yeah I have done that, can it be the linq2rest that messes it up?

Comment: Does setting the charset of the context manually help? `consultants.Response.Charset = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;`

Comment: where am I suppose to type that :S

Comment: I guess you could do it in `public ConsultantContext`substituting `consultants` with `restContext`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11312/discussion-between-jurgemaister-and-rammtin-avar)

Comment: We narrowed that the problem is in the XML